# Consultas en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create database Ventas;

   use Ventas;

create table Producto
(
Id_producto int,
RFC_Proveedor varchar(14),
Descripcion_producto varchar(40),
Precio_venta decimal(7,2),
Precio_compra decimal(7,2),
Id_producto_asociado int,
nombre_departamento varchar(40)
primary key(Id_producto)
);

create table Proveedor
(
RFC_Proveedor varchar(14),
Nombre_proveedor varchar(40),
Telefono_proveedor varchar(14),
Direccion_proveedor varchar(50),
Forma_de_pago varchar(12),
primary key(RFC_Proveedor)
);

Alter table "Producto"
add  foreign key ("RFC_Proveedor")
references "Proveedor" ("RFC_Proveedor") 
on update cascade on delete no action;

/*Agregue Un proveedor llamado “Juan López”,
cuyo teléfono es “235145847”, tiene su dirección en “Lucio 20”,
su forma de pago es de “Contado” y su RFC es “ELP720315GN4”.*/

insert into Proveedor (RFC_Proveedor,Nombre_proveedor,Telefono_proveedor,Direccion_proveedor,Forma_de_pago)
values('juan Lopez','235145847','Lucio 20','Contado','ELP720315GN4');  


/* Agregue un producto con descripción “TV LCD”
con un precio de venta de “$15,000.00” 
y compra de “$10,000.00”, sin un ID asociado,
el cual pertenece al departamento de “Electrónica”
y el rfc del proveedor que lo surte es “ELP720315GN4”. 
Este producto tendrá el código 1.*/


/*Encontrar el nombre del departamento
y el precio de venta máximo por cada nombre del departamento.*/


/*Obtener la descripción de los productos, el nombre del departamento 
y el nombre del proveedor de todos los productos*/

/*Encontrar la descripción de los productos que tienen un producto asociado, 
mostrando el id y descripción del producto y la descripción del producto asociado.*/


/*Obtener la descripción del producto y su precio de compra 
de todos los productos que tienen un precio de compra mayor al 
precio de compra promedio de la tabla productos. Ordene los resultados en 
forma ascendente de acuerdo al precio de compra.*/
```

He creado esta base de datos. Necesito hacer las consultas mencionadas en los comentarios, pero estoy empezando con SQL. ¿Pueden ayudarme o indicarme como empezar con las consultas?

!Gracias!

Comment: El problema principal que veo, es que no tienes suficientes datos insertados en cada tabla y a la hora de verificar las consultas se te hará tedioso.

Comment: de hecho apenas soy nuevo y apenas estoy aprendiendo a insertar datos.

Comment: Bienvenido, ¿nos muestras que has investigado o hecho por tu cuenta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!Buenas!

He querido ayudarte con el ejercicio, con el tema de las consultas. Veo que ya has creado un **INSERT** para introducir datos, por lo que veo innecesario explicarte esa parte y menos insertar yo los datos.

Primera consulta:

```
SELECT nombre_departamento, MAX(precio_venta) from producto GROUP BY nombre_departamento, precio_venta;
```

**SELECT** es para mostrar u obtener los datos que queremos.

**MAX()** obtenemos el precio mayor.

**FROM** para seleccionar la tabla

**GROUP BY** para agrupar por nombres y precios los datos.

Segunda consulta:

```
SELECT nombre_departamento, descripcion_producto, proveedor.Nombre_proveedor FROM producto, proveedor WHERE producto.RFC_Proveedor = proveedor.RFC_Proveedor;
```

**WHERE** para indicar la condición a cumplir, en este caso, que el RFC.Proveedor sea igual en la tabla **producto** y **proveedor**.

Tercera consulta:

```
select id_producto, id_producto_asociado, descripcion_producto from producto where id_producto_asociado <> null;
```

**<>** Es un operador para indicar la diferencia, es decir, que un elemento sea distinto a otro. Y he introducido **null**, ya que solo necesitamos los que tengan el campo con datos e ignoramos los vacíos.

Cuarta consulta:

```
select descripcion_producto, precio_compra from producto where precio_compra > (select AVG(precio_compra) from producto) ORDER BY precio_compra ASC;
```

**Subconsulta** Es lo que he realizado para comparar que el **precio_compra** sea mayor a el de la subconsulta. Es decir, lo que esta dentro del paréntesis, es otra consulta para obtener el **promedio del precio_compra**.

**AVG** Hace el promedio de un numero.

**ORDER BY** Ordena y con **ASC** indicamos que lo haga ascendente.

Espero haberte ayudado no solo ha realizar el ejercicio, sino a entender un poco la estructura de las consultas en SQL.

Comment: Si resuelve tu pregunta, por favor marca respondida. !Gracias!

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas no suelen ser bien recibidas por la comunidad, incumple varias reglas del sitio, pero lo más grave, para mí, es que parece un trabajo académico, el OP no mostró hasta ahora ningún esfuerzo ni intento de resolverlo. Habría que evitar responderlas en primer lugar. Bien, ahora, lo únicos que pueden explicarte su voto y no deberían por que hacerlo, son quienes lo emitieron (el voto es secreto). podría ser una mala respuesta o simplemente una "opinión" por haber respondido una pregunta que va camino al cierre. Saludos.